# How to use ISNULL function in ms-access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have database table with following fields

FieldId
FieldGroupId
FieldName

I need to select FieldGroupId from Fields table where FieldId = "?" and iff FieldGroupId is empty it should return some default value.

Following query does not work if FieldID is not present in databse.

```
select IIf(IsNull(FieldGroupID),"AA",FieldGroupID) from Fields where FieldID ='ALPHAA'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will be doing this from within an Access application session, you can use `DLookup()` to retrieve the `FieldGroupID` value which matches your `FieldID` value.

```
DLookup("FieldGroupID", "[Fields]", "FieldID ='ALPHAA'")
```

`DLookup()` will give you Null when `FieldID` is not found.  You can use the `Nz()` function to substitute your desired value for Null.

```
Nz(DLookup("FieldGroupID", "[Fields]", "FieldID ='ALPHAA'"), "AA")
```

Comment: This result obtain from above query returns more than one row as AA,AA,AA.....actually it should return only one row